# Qual versão do visual studio, suporta asp clássico?

Tags: visual-studio, asp

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<TITLE>Seu título aqui</TITLE>

</HEAD>  

<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">

<%

response.write("Hello world")


%>
</BODY>  

</HTML>
```

Comment: Todas as versões.

Answer (score 1):

Em primeiro lugar, por padrão, quando você abre um site no Visual Studio, você está abrindo através do `file system`, não via `IIS`. Portanto, o Visual Studio usa um servidor de web interno chamado `Cassini`, em vez do `IIS`.

O servidor web `Cassini` **NÃO executa ASP clássico**. O `IIS` sim. Então a primeira coisa que você precisa fazer é descobrir como depurar no `IIS`.

Você precisa ter o `IIS` instalado na máquina que você está trabalhando, e ter o site que você está utilizando configurado da mesma maneira do servidor. (Assim, você consegue executar *http: // localhost / algumapasta* e ver o seu site)

Também precisa anexar ao `running process` do Internet Explorer.

Em seguida, você precisa fazer o Visual Studio reconhecer o `IIS` e executar o seu site, em vez de usar o servidor web embutido; e ativar a depuração.

Para ver um passo-a-passo com imagens (é antigo mas ainda deve funcionar) dessa configuração, dá uma olhada nesse [artigo do CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio).

Realmente é um pouco confuso, mas espero ter ajudado.